# Clicking Tab / Finding next Text Field - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

So I am testing out selenium, and am trying to fill in a simple form online. it just asks for an email, first name, last name, and phone. I got it to input the email (the first text field), but now I cannot seem to get it to get to the next text field. I tried having it press the tab key, but that is not working. Here is the error I am getting, along with the code:

```
def test_search_in_python_org(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(URL) #uses the URL that was generated at the start of the task

    content = driver.find_element_by_name('EMAIL').send_keys(userEmail)
    content.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

    content = driver.find_element_by_name('FNAME')
    content.send_keys(firstName) #pastes firstname

    content = driver.find_element_by_name('LNAME')
    content.send_keys(lastName) #pastes lastname

    content = driver.find_element_by_name('PHONE')
    content.send_keys(phone) #pastes phone
    time.sleep(1000)
```

in terminal:

> File "raffleBot.py", line 34, in test_search_in_python_org
>       content.send_keys(Keys.TAB) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Anyone have any suggestions to get the tab key to work? or, on a different route, have selenium simply find the next available text field?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: from your code snippet there doesnt look to be any reason to send TAB as you are already finding the next element by name and dont need to TAB to it

Comment: welp im an idiot haha - prime example of me overthinking things. thanks so much.